# How to get type of file on Mac OS X?

Tags: java, macos, file, filesystems, file-type

I am using this code to get the type of file -

```
FileSystemView filesystem = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();
String sFileType = filesystem.getSystemTypeDescription(file))
```

Under Windows, this code works file, shows type of file correcly. But under Mac OS X, it does not show anything with this code. Method `getSystemTypeDescription` says:

> Override for platforms with native ShellFolder implementations.

How to do it and how can we get type of files on Mac OS X?

Comment: What you are talking about is overriding native code -- most likely this will mean implementing some JNI.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Quaqua](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/) library that have a class [OSXLionFileSystemView](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/javadoc/ch/randelshofer/quaqua/lion/filechooser/OSXLionFileSystemView.html) that is the overridden version of the default FileSystemView and should work fine on OS X Lion ...